# google docs boldText until semicolon line by line app script error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs-api, method-signature, line-by-line

```
function boldTextInLines() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var text = body.getText();

  var lines = text.split("\n"); 

  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var line = lines[i];
    var endPos = line.indexOf(':');
    console.log(endPos);
    
    if (endPos !== -1) {
      
      body.editAsText().setBold(i, 0, endPos, true);
    }else{
      console.log(endPos);
    }
    
  }
}
```

> Exception: The parameters (number,number,number,(class)) don't match the method signature for DocumentApp.Text.setBold. boldTextInLines  @ Kod.gs:14

This is the error that was thrown and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function boldTextInLines() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

  var body = doc.getBody();

  var text = body.getText();
 

  var lines = text.split("\n"); 
  console.log(lines)
  
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var line = lines[i];
    console.log(line)
    var endPos = line.indexOf(":");
    console.log(endPos);

    
    if (endPos!==-1) {

      var textBeforeColon = line.substring(0, endPos);
      var startIndex = body.getText().indexOf(textBeforeColon);
      var endIndex = startIndex + textBeforeColon.length;
      console.log(textBeforeColon)
      body.editAsText().setBold(startIndex,endIndex, true);
    }else{

    }
    
  }
}
```

firstly, setBold should be setBold(startPos,endPos,true)
secondly, when the code runs, up to ":" the words will not be bold,
since the first "endPos" parameter represents a different position within the line rather than the document, the expected result wouldn't be achieved even if you correct it. An adjusted version of the setBold function with correct start and end positions is included in the code.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: explanation added to the solution